# Determining isomorphism classes of $K[[X]]$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $K$ be a field. Determine all isomorphic classes of $K[[X]]$-modules with $K$-dimension 3. For each of these modules $M$, give a $K$-basis and the matrix of the map $M\to M, m\mapsto Xm$ with respect to such basis.

Here is $K[[X]]$ the field of power series.

I got this question from my module ring theory course, in which we get a small part of module theory. My problem is that I don't know how to even begin with this problem, the only idea that I have is to use the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID, but I'm having a lot of difficulty understanding how to use it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain the $d_i$ are either $0$ or $X^l$, as every ideal of $R=K[[X]]$ is either $\{0\}$ or $(X^n)$ for some $n$.

Comment: I see, so does that mean that if $M$ is a $K[[X]]$-module, then we can write $M\cong K[[X]]\oplus K[[X]]/(X^0)\oplus K[[X]]/(X)\oplus ... \oplus K[[X]]/(X^n)$ for some $n$. We know that the dimension of $K[[X]]$ is equal to 1, because the dimension of a field is equal to 0 and $\dim K[X]=\dim K[[X]] = \dim K + 1 = 1$. I suppose because of that we want $n=2$ and so $M\cong K[[X]]\oplus K[[X]]/(X^2)$ or $M\cong K[[X]]\oplus K[[X]]/(X)\oplus K[[X]]/(X)$. I don't know if this is right so any feedback is appreciated.